# (Sum) query results in jtext

Tags: java, sql-server

i want to create a function to show me the `sum` in `Jtextfield` .I dont know how to call the result any idea ? 
My `jtextfieldname` is `sum_calc` .Ty

```
public void getSum() {

             Connection con =getConnection();
             Statement st;
             PreparedStatement pst = null;
             ResultSet rs;
            try{
                String qquery=" SELECT sum(Receipt.Sales_Quantity * Receipt.Pro_Price) AS TotalItemsOrdered FROM Receipt";
              pst=con.prepareStatement(qquery);
                             pst.setString(1,sum_calc );
                             rs=pst.executeQuery();

           if(rs.next()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, qquery);

            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "zero");
            }

        }catch (Exception e) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e); }

    };
```

Here is the `button` that call the function

```
 private void make_Receipt_sumActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        getSum();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public void getSum() {

         Connection con =getConnection();
         Statement st;
         PreparedStatement pst = null;
         ResultSet rs;
        try{
            String qquery=" SELECT sum(Receipt.Sales_Quantity * Receipt.Pro_Price) AS TotalItemsOrdered FROM Receipt";
          pst=con.prepareStatement(qquery);
                         //pst.setString(1,qquery );
                         rs=pst.executeQuery();

         if(rs.next()){
              float TotalItemsOrdered = rs.getFloat("TotalItemsOrdered");
              float nvNum=TotalItemsOrdered;
             sum_calc.setText(valueOf(nvNum));
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rs);

         }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not Found");
        }

    }catch (Exception e) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e); }

}
```